# std::bind a regular function but with an epilogue

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, std

I have a particular callback (that is defined in some 'C' land) that needs to be padded with some additional work that is not part of the callback function. It goes something like this...

```
typedef void (*callback_func)(int);
extern int set_callback(callback_func cb);
```

In my C++ code, I need to set_value a promise that is defined outside the scope of the callback, in my class. So, I'd have to capture the std::promise member variable or alternatively *this* and send to the callback, then set it once the callback has been invoked, only that the compiler doesn't like it. I do it this way,

```
set_callback([this](int x) {
   // some code ...
     prom.set_value(true);
});
```

Below is the snipped error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'set_callback'
        set_callback([this](int var) {
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from '(lambda at xxx ' to 'callback_func'
          (aka 'void (*)(int)') for 1st argument
```

I realize that, I need to somehow "bind" the regular function to make the callback function an std::function, but am unsure of the way to accomplish that - not to mention send it a parameter and perform the epilogue. Please suggest, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas can only decay to function pointers if the capture list is empty. This is because the code

```
[this](int x) {
   // some code ...
     prom.set_value(true);
}
```

Is roughly equivalent to

```
struct SomeLambdaName {
    MyCapture self;

    auto operator()(int x) const {
        // some code ...
        self.prom.set_value(true);
    }
};
```

On the other hand, function pointers are just that: pointers. A pointer to the address of the function to call.

In C++, a member function:

```
struct MyClass {
    int i;
    int add_x(int x) { return i = i + x; }
};
```

Is roughly like this C code (implementation dependent):

```
int add_x(MyClass *self, int x) { return self->i = self->i + x; }
```

---

If the C code can be changed to take a `void *` to hold arbitrary data, this can be done:

```
typedef void (*callback_func)(int, void * data);
extern int set_callback(callback_func cb);
```

```
set_callback([](int x, void * data) {
     MyClass &self = *reinterpret_cast<MyClass *>(data);
     // some code ...
     self.prom.set_value(true);
});
```

Otherwise, you'd have to have static objects or something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, the C code cannot be changed! In response to what you have proposed, you are suggesting passing the this pointer as a void* and casting it within (it would have been more consistent to have the void* data being passed in as the first parameter - essentially, that is what the this pointer is), but I believe there is a better approach of binding the C function to an std::function and then following up with an epilogue, but I am not sure how.

Comment: @chimp45 As I was saying, it is **impossible** to bind a C function to a `std::function`.

Comment: @chimp45 function pointers include definition of calling conventions, "C" or "C++" and specifiers. Pointer  to C++ function in that is not compatible with C without use of extern "C". Also that's why they cant be bound to be used as C pointer. Second, you can't pass "this" to C unless class  is a trivial  and POD. you need to create n extern "C" function in C++ code that would do  proper work inside